# grant execute on utl_file to user in Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

```
sqlplus connect <sys>/<pwd>
grant execute on utl_file to <user>
connect <user>/<pwd>
DESC utl_file
```

then i get:
ORA-24372: invalid object for describe

How can I access to UTL_FIL from other users in 11g xe? I already tried with public as well

Answer (score 1):

The grant worked just fine. You can't DESC a package or procedure, which is why you're getting an error.

Documentation for UTL_FILE is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm). It provides sample PL/SQL that shows you how to use the package.

A short code snippet that sums up its functionality is [here](http://psoug.org/snippet/Oracle-PL-SQL-UTL_FILE-file-write-to-file-example_538.htm).

Comment: why if I do it under SYS I can DESC it? Also in can desc it in the full version of 11g

Comment: @Edu is correct, his example can be successfully reproduced in my 11gR2 Enterprise environment, including `DESC`.